Are there any special rules for the squaring of infinitesimals?
The teacher used the method of infinitesimals to prove the Taylor expansion of Cos(x). However, there was a step in the derivation that involved squaring an infinitesimal, which I found somewhat problematic. I'm not sure if there are any special rules for the squaring of infinitesimals.
Here is the teacher's calculation process,
$$
\begin{gathered}
\cos x=1-2 \sin ^2 \frac{x}{z} \\
  \hspace{6em} =1-2\left(\frac{x}{2}+o\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)^2 \\
\hspace{10em}=1-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{1}{2} o(x)^2-\frac{o(x) \times x}{2}
\end{gathered}
$$
With the key step being the third one. Shouldn't it be that：
$=1-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{1}{2} o(x)^2-o(x) \times x$
In the expansion of the perfect square formula, the second term has a coefficient of 2, and there is also a coefficient of 2 outside the parentheses? These two 2's, together with the 1/4 in the second term of the perfect square expansion, should cancel each other out completely, right?


In response to Lulu's comment, if we follow the teacher's continued derivation, we get: $=1-\frac{x^2}{2}- o(x^2)$
If we follow my derivation, we get: $=1-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{3}{2} o(x^2)$
However, the correct answer is: $=1-\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2)$
So, can I conclude that 1, 2, and 3 are equal? Because multiplying an infinitesimal by a bounded quantity still results in an infinitesimal, and 1, 0.5, and -1 are all bounded quantities. Is my understanding correct?

There is no difference between $o(x)$, $o(x/2)$, and $o(x)/2$.

Convince yourself that those things are all the same.  Note:  you have a stray $z$ in your first line.  I assume that should have been a $2$.

@lulu I have added a supplementary reply at the bottom of the main text. Could you please check if my understanding is correct?

Do you know what $o(f(x))$ means?   Use the definition to prove that $c\times o(f(x))=o(f(x))$ for any non-zero constant $c$.

@lulu Thank you for your comment, I understand now. I didn't notice this property of infinitesimals.

I wouldn't refer to this as a property of "infinitesimals".  It holds for large $x$ as well.

@lulu "Use the definition to prove that c×o(f(x))=o(f(x)) for any non-zero constant c."---Isn't this the property of infinitesimals? Isn't it precisely based on this property that the problem in the main text was solved? This shows that the three calculation results are equivalent.

To use little $o$ notation, you should specify a limit.  The property I mentioned is independent of what that limit is...it could be infinite, that's a standard use.  Here, yes, they clearly mean $x\to 0$.

Try to think of the little o/big O/Omega/Theta notations not as individual functions but as equivalence classes of functions.

Notations such as $O(f(x)),,o(f(x))$ denote sets of functions viz.$$\sin\frac{x}{2}\in\frac{x}{2}+o(x)\implies\cos x=1-2\sin^2\frac{x}{2}\in1-\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2).$$For rules, see here (in particular, Theorem 2 here).

This is a very reasonable question, I think, though in this year the conventional viewpoint in mathematics does not directly allow "infinitesimals".
Nevertheless, in fact, the Landau little-oh notation is a legitimate incarnation of infinitesimals, I think, including "taking the standard part", as in Ed Nelson's version.
But, yes, it differs at-least-superficially from other formalizations of "infinitesimal", since $2\cdot \epsilon\not=\epsilon$ for infinitesimal $\epsilon$, while $2 o(x)=o(x)$ (as $x\to 0$, for example). The difference is substantially that the little-oh notation also includes some implicit "taking the standard part", so that, yes, the "standard parts" of $o(x)$ and $2o(x)$ are the same.
I think that the Landau set-up is a very insightful compromise between overt talking about infinitesimals, and constant recitation of the epsilon-delta mantra. :)

Whose conventional viewpoint is that? :-)
